# Скрипт произвольно завершает работу

Tags: javascript, node.js, сокет, arduino, emmet

В общем такая проблема, код снизу работает, но через 1-2 минуты перестает работать без вывода каких либо ошибок.
Если закомментировать строку:

```
io.emit('update', {'temperature': temp});
```

То скрипт работает вечно.

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = socket.listen(app.listen(8080));

var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8, 
    parity: 'none', 
    stopBits: 1, 
    flowControl: false 
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    var remoteAddress = client.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log('New client ' + remoteAddress);
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {    
    console.log('Serial port is open');
});


serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    temp = data.toString();

    try {
         io.emit('update', {'temperature': temp});
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    process.stdout.write(temp);
});

serialPort.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Serial port is closed');
});

serialPort.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Something wrong... ' + error);
});
```

С чем связано никак не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть ещё и в кривых данных. Приходит какой-нибудь перенос строки, конвертируется в NULL. При попытке записать его в сокет, происходит тихий вылет.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю к скрипту подключаются клиенты, `io.broadcast.emit('update', {'temperature': temp})` сообщает им температуру. Значит при очередной отправке скрипт вылетает с какой-то ошибкой. Попробуйте изменить на:

```
try {
    io.broadcast.emit('update', {'temperature': temp});
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Нет. Все так же никакой ошибки нет. Скрипт молча перестает работать 
[http://prntscr.com/8zzhec](http://prntscr.com/8zzhec)

Comment: @Марк а откуда вы взяли сам код `io.broadcast.emit`? Я что-то в документации не вижу такого примера. В документации просто идет: `io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');`

Comment: Исправил на io.emit('update', {'temperature': temp}); разницы никакой(

Comment: @Марк а попробуйте добавить отлов закрытия потока с Arduino, т.е. `serialPort.on("close", function () {    
    console.log('Serial port is close');
});`

Comment: Пробовал ставить событие и на close и на error. Никакое событие не срабатывает.

Comment: Выложил весь код. Может я не замечаю чего то очевидного...

Comment: @Марк блин, а попробуйте добавил колбек к эмиту, `socket.emit('update', {'temperature': temp}, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}); ` может это что-нибудь даст.

Comment: Ругается он так. [Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting]

Comment: @Марк если честно, то уже не знаю, куда копать. В socket.io есть debug режим, может он поможет?